# Understand how data is retrieved from function

Tags: arduino

I've started learning C for Arduino for about 2 weeks. I have the following code and I don't understand how data is retrieved from function ReadLine. Also I don't understand how variable BufferCount affects the program and why it is used. I do know that it holds the number of digits the year have but that's about all I know about this variable.

From what I've learned so far a function is composed of:

- function type specifier
- function name
- function arguments.

What I see in this program makes me think that the function can also return values using the argument part. I always thought that a function can only return a value that is the same type (int, boolean ...) as the type specifier.

```cpp
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.avaible() > 0) {
    int bufferCount;
    int year;
    char myData[20];
    bufferCount = ReadLine (myData);
    year = atoi(myData); //convert string to int
    Serial.print("Year: ");
    Serial.print(year);
    if (IsLeapYear(year)) {
      Serial.print(" is ");
    } else {
      Serial.print(" is not ");
    }
    Serial.println("a leap year");
  }
}

int IsLeapYear(int yr) {
  if  (yr % 4 == 0 && yr % 100 != 0 || yr % 400 == 0) {
    return 1; //it's a leap year
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}

int ReadLine (char str[]) {
  char c;
  int index = 0;
  while (true) {
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
      c = Serial.read();
      if (c != '\n') {
        str[index++] = c;
      } else {
        str[index] = '\0'; //null termination character
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return index;
}
```

Comment: `bufferCount = ReadLine (myData);` gives information to `bufferCount` **and** into the buffer `myData`. The first is the length of the data, the second was written directly into the buffer (by its pointer) supplied to the function.

Comment: Learn about pointers.

Comment: suggest reading a tutorial book (and performing the associated examples) on the C language.  Stackoverflow is not an online tutorial site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental concept you are missing is pointers.  In the case of a function like isLeapYear there, you'd be right about that parameter.  It is just a copy of the data from whatever variable was passed in when the function gets called.

But with ReadLine things are different.  ReadLine is getting a pointer to a char array.  A pointer is a special kind of variable that holds the memory address of another variable.  And it is true that in this case you are getting a local copy of the pointer, but it still points to the same location in memory.  And during the function, data is copied not into the variable str, but to the memory location it points to.  Since that is a memory location that belongs to a variable in the scope of the calling function, that actual variable's value will be changed.  You've written over it in memory.